# Is it correct practice to bypass useState in some scenarios?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have two states in my React component:

```
// Selected item state
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(null);

// Toggle callout visibility
const [isCalloutVisible, setIsCalloutVisible] = React.useState(false);
```

I have a reset function to reset my states. To prevent a double re-render, I am bypassing setIsCalloutVisible:

```
const reset = () => {
  isCalloutVisible = false;
  setSelectedItem(null);
}
```

Is this the correct approach? Or is there a cleaner way to reset both states in a single re-render?

[edit] thanks for the first comments and reply, and clearly merging both into a single state would help. What I'd be interested to understand is why my current approach is not correct, and what the negative effects are.

Comment: It is not. The correct approach is "find out which actions trigger double rendering, then find out _why_ it triggers double rendering, and then fixing that".

Comment: So that's my issue. I have two states to reset, and I can't figure out how to do it properly without double rendering.

Comment: If these values are tied together, turn them into a single state so you can update them simultaneous.

Comment: They are only loosely tied - for example the callout could be displayed/hidden without any change to the state of the selected item. I was hoping to keep the states separate for readability but I get your point.

Comment: No, you shouldn't ever mutate your state object, this is an anti-pattern. Is there an issue with a "double render"? As in, does a second render cause a problem for your app? Why can't you reset both at the same time within the same render cycle? What is causing anything to double render? Please provide more context.

Comment: @DrewReese maybe this is what I am missing. I am assuming the first React state update will trigger a re-render without waiting for the other state update. Could you show in an answer how to reset both in the same cycle?

Comment: React batches state updates. Just because you setState doesn't mean those immediately trigger a render. React will not "wait for the other update", it just flat out "waits for a good moment to execute whatever the pending aggregate state update is". So as per Drew's question: is there a _problem_ caused by double rendering? Because if there is, then those two values are not loosely coupled: updates should only ever happen to the pair, even if one of them is sometimes kept the same value.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I assumed the first setState would interrupt the current execution.to start a re-render. I certainly need to better understand state management and hooks, starting with Drew's replies.

Comment: The react docs are also an excellent source of (re)familiarizing yourself with the intricacies, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation covers some important aspects

Comment: Ah, assumptions... will get you every time. No, it's as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans describes... all the enqueued state updates from any single render cycle are essentially "aggregated together" almost like a "single" update. At a minimum, because of the way the Javascript Event Loop works, React needs to wait for ***at least*** the function enqueuing multiple updates to complete before it can even start any state updates. Does this aspect clear it up a little and make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following component state:

```
// Selected item state
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(null);

// Toggle callout visibility
const [isCalloutVisible, setIsCalloutVisible] = React.useState(false);
```

If you wanted to reset both state values in a single callback just enqueue both state updates.

```
const reset = () => {
  setSelectedItem(null);
  setIsCalloutVisible(false);
}
```

All React state updates from a single render cycle are batch processed *between* render cycles and the computed state is returned for the next cycle.

[State updates may be Asynchronous & Batched](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks! What still holds me back is the "may be" part, which makes it sound unreliable.

Comment: @Christophe It's abundantly clear that during *any* render cycle that react state is const, it can't be updated, reinforced by the fact that it is also closed over in the function scope of the component definition. I don't think you should let the title of that section throw you off. I'd have to dig a bit for docs/blogs/etc but I am certain that React's stance on state updates won't ever change, there's just too much deterministic logic wrapped up in knowing state is constant within a render cycle and the cycle update is what gates all updates. React is a state machine with snapshot views.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like this

```
const [data, setData] = react.useState({ 
  isCalloutVisible: false, 
  selectedItem: null 
})
const reset = () => {
  setData({
    isCalloutVisible: false,
    selectedItem: false
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely address the issue. I chose @drew-reese 's answer because I find the code easier to read with separate states, and it will be easier to scale up to additional states.